# Custom fields with foreign keys in mutliple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**[UPDATE 2 : SOLUTION]: Finally, the solution is to make two different queries :**
The first query loops the Items (without their custom fields):

```
$itemsQuery = 'SELECT * FROM itemsTable";
$items = $db->Exectue($itemsQuery);
```

Then, in the loop of the items, i make a second query to match the right customs fields :

```
//FIRST LOOP => Render the items
while ($row = $items->FetchRow())
{

//Query the custom fields within the Items loop
$customFieldsQuery = 'SELECT item.id,
customFieldName.id, customFieldName.value as fieldName,
customFieldValue.id, customFieldValue.customFieldNameId customFieldValue.value as fieldValue

FROM itemsTable AS item
LEFT JOIN customFieldNameTable as customFieldName
    ON item.id = customFieldName.id
LEFT JOIN customFieldValueTable as customFieldValue
    ON customFieldValue.customFieldNameId = customFieldValue.id
WHERE item.id = '.$row['id'].'';

$customFields = $db->Execute($customFieldsQuery)

//Loop the custom fields BY item
while ($row2 = $fields->FetchRow()){
    // Show item title (unique)
     echo $row['title'] . "<br/>";
   //Show custom fields
    echo $row2['fieldName'] . " : " . $row2['fieldValue'];


}
}
```

**[UPDATE] My bad, i forgot to precise that each item has several custom fields, so the problem with the joint is that it renders several items (one for each custom field. Also, Group_concat isn't a solution, because i need to access to each custom field, independently, due to the user interface of the site**

Let's say I have 3 tables :

```
Table ITEMS store the id, title of an Item (Rows : id, title)
```

The two others tables are for custom fields :

- Table `FIELDNAME` stores the name that we give to the custom field :
  Rows : id, id_item (foreign key to retrieve the right item), value
- Table `FIELDVALUE` stores the value we give to the custom field and has a foreign key to connect to it's name value from FIELDNAME :
  Rows : id, id_item (foreign key to retrieve the right item), id_fieldname (foreign key to retrieve the right field name), value

Example :

```
Table ITEMS :
id = 1
title = "title of the item"

Table FIELDNAME :
(id = 1)
id_item  = 1
value = "Country"

Table FIELDVALUE :
(id = 1)
id_item = 1
id_fieldname = 1
Value = "France"
```

What I want to do, is a query that links the 3 tables so that I can do something like that :

```
while ($row = $myQuery->FetchRow())
{
    {$row['item_title']} => output "Title of the item"

    {$row['field.country']} => Output "Country: France"
}
```

`$row['field.country']` would be a sort of concatenation of fieldname : fieldval.

I've almost found a good result with SQl's GROUP_CONCAT, but the problem is that it output all the custom fields in one row, though i need to access to each independently (something like

```
{$row['fieldname.country']} => "Country"
{$row['fieldname.country.value']} => "France"")
```

Comment: what is the relation ship between those 3 tables i think it is like item : fieldname on to many and field name to value one to one is it correct

Answer (score 0):

You can create a join across all tables - but you might need to alias the fields if you're fetching the result into an array in PHP.

You may also need to backtick `FIELDNAME.value` and `FIELDVALUE.value` since `value` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
ITEMS.id AS item_id,
ITEMS.title AS item_title,
FIELDNAME.id AS fieldname_id,
FIELDNAME.`value` AS fieldname_string,
FIELDVALUE.id AS fieldvalue_id,
FIELDVALUE.`value` AS fieldvalue_string

FROM ITEMS

INNER JOIN FIELDNAME
    ON FIELDNAME.id_item = ITEMS.id

INNER JOIN FIELDVALUE
    ON FIELDVALUE.id_item = ITEMS.id
    AND FIELDVALUE.id_fieldname = FIELDNAME.id
```

If you're fetching that with something like `mysqli_result::fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` you should end up with each row as an array like this:

```
array (
    'item_id' => 1,
    'item_title' => "Title of the item",
    'fieldname_id' => 1,
    'fieldname_string' => "Country",
    'fieldvalue_id' => 1,
    'fieldvalue_string' => "France"
)
```

As an aside, if `FIELDVALUE.id_item` + `FIELDVALUE.id_fieldname` is a unique combination you could create a compound primary key instead of using the (presumably) auto-incremented `FIELDVALUE.id`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. My bad, i forgot to precise that there are several custom fields for one item (ex: "Country: France" + "Type: Article" etc...). Actually, FIELDVALUE.id_item + FIELDVALUE.id_fieldname are well a unique combination, but i can't modify the Table. So problem with your solution, is that it returns several items (one for each custom field), that's why i said in my original post that GROUP_CONCAT almost do the trick. The problem with GROUP_CONCAT is that i can't access to each custom field independtly (according to the UI i need to display the title between 2 custom fields)

Comment: So those custom fields are in another table? (which would make sense)

Comment: Yes in two different Tables : one that store the name given to the custom field (eg "Country"), the other one stores the value (eg "France"). I think that maybe the solution would be to make a first query that looks for the Items, then in the loop make a second query to find the right custom fields? I'm trying to do so, but i don't know how to make a while loop inside another while loop...

Comment: Looks like you've sorted it now anyway :) All's well that ends well as they say!

Answer (score 0):

use following query you can get it using inner join

```
 SELECT i.title ,fn.value as filed_name,fd.value as field_value
 from ITEMS i inner join FIELDNAME fn 
on fn.id_item=i.id inner join FIELDVALUE fd on fd.id_fieldname = fn.id
```

Comment: you will get all title and its field name and values

Comment: Thank you for this answer, too. Unfortunately, as i said just above, problem is that each item has several custom fields. So it's like i need to make a loop for the custom fields inside the loop of the items (but i don't know how?)

Answer (score -1):

So you will need [SQL Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

Comment: You could have at least tailored it to match the fields in question rather than just blithely copy/pasting from w3schools...